# How to install bash completion

Tags: bash, macos

I see this project:

https://github.com/scop/bash-completion

and I wanna have the bash completion installed.

I know that I have to source a file, but that repo is big, so which file should I source?

I am on mac os Mojave

Answer (score 0):

Following the repo's README, it looks like you can use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php) to install the bash-completion package. 
After install macports, `port install bash-completion`